# How can I cut an image from the bottom using PHP?

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to take out the text in the bottom of an image. How can I cut it from bottom ...say 10 pixels to cut from bottom.

I want do this in PHP. I have lots of images that have text in the bottom.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: are we trying to remove somebody's watermark programmatically?

Answer (score 20):

Here you go.

To change the name of the image, change $in_filename (currently 'source.jpg'). You can use URLs in there as well, although obviously that will perform worse.

Change the $new_height variable to set how much of the bottom you want cropped.

Play around with $offset_x, $offset_y, $new_width and $new_height, and you'll figure it out.

Please let me know that it works. :)

Hope it helps!

```
<?php

$in_filename = 'source.jpg';

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);

$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 0;

$new_height = $height - 15;
$new_width = $width;

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($in_filename);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_image);

?>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the help, that worked. Now i need to save that new image in a dir.. how can i do that?

Comment: I don't want to be a pain in the neck, but would you mind marking my answer as the correct one? :) That's what we're all about around here. ;)

Comment: Sorry guys i cant vote up for you as my reputation is only 11 :(

Comment: @nazir, you should see a check beside Helgi's answer. You should mark that one if you feel that he's got your question answered.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [GD Image Library](http://www.php.net/gd) to manipulate images in PHP. The function you're looking for is `imagecopy()`, which copies part of an image onto another. Here's an example from PHP.net that does roughly what you describe:

```
<?php

$width = 50;
$height = 50;

$source_x = 0;
$source_y = 0;

// Create images
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg('source.jpg');
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Copy
imagecopy($source, $new, 0, 0, $source_x, $source_y, $width, $height);

// Output image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new);

?>
```

To crop the source image, change the `$source_x` and `$source_y` variables to your liking.

Comment: can someone please show me a working code for my need - thanks a lot

Comment: You might be mistaking SO for a group of developers who will do your work for free.

Comment: @nazir: There's a typo on the last line. Change `imagejpeg($dest)` to `imagejpeg($new)`.